# When I write the awk script it print one line multiple times

Tags: awk

I have written this script it print same line multiple times.  what to do if I want to print it only one time?

```
BEGIN {print "Average of salary"}
cnt=cnt+1
total=total+$3
avg=total/cnt
END {printf "Number of records:%d avg is:%d",cnt,avg}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you didn't enclose the below code within braces as following and `awk` will meet those as True statement and print every line it read:

```
{
    cnt=cnt+1
    total=total+$3
    avg=total/cnt
}
```

But instead you could do something like:

```
awk '{ avg=(total+=$3)/NR } END{ print "...", NR, avg }' <infile
```

The `NR` value is incrementing on each record/line `awk` reads from the input file, means that when *awk* read all lines the value of `NR` is the line number  of the last line (basically it points to the **R**ecord **N**umber)

Answer (score 1):

You almost make it.

enclose compute line in {} like

```
BEGIN { ...}
{ compute goes here}
END { printf "..."}
```

## why triple print ?

every assignation like `foo=$3+foo` is a positive test to awk, and default action is to print line.

(and by the way, you only need to compute average in `END` clause)